# Installing passenger on ClearOS

Tags: phusion-passenger, clearos

I have ClearOS distro istalled on a server (should be centos 7 based distro) and i want to use phusion passenger on it. But when i try to install it i run into this error:

```
       Error: Package: passenger-5.0.22-8.el7.x86_64 (passenger)
       Requires: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-60.el7
       Installed: selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7_1.21.noarch (@clearos-centos-updates)
           selinux-policy = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.21
       Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7.noarch (clearos-centos)
           selinux-policy = 3.13.1-23.el7
       Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7_1.7.noarch (clearos-centos-updates)
           selinux-policy = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.7
       Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7_1.8.noarch (clearos-centos-updates)
           selinux-policy = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.8
       Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7_1.13.noarch (clearos-centos-updates)
           selinux-policy = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.13
       Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7_1.17.noarch (clearos-centos-updates)
           selinux-policy = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.17
       Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-23.el7_1.18.noarch (clearos)
           selinux-policy = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.18
```

I cant figure out whats missing or how could i update the selinux-policy so it will work with passenger.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
yum remove selinux-policy
```

then:

```
rpm -Uvh http://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1511.00/selinux-policy/20151120104451/3.13.1-60.el7.x86_64/selinux-policy-3.13.1-60.el7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1511.00/selinux-policy/20151120104451/3.13.1-60.el7.x86_64/selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Or wait until it resolves trough updates...

I tried enabling centos plus, but it didn't help...